# email validation using enums in java or state machine

Tags: java, validation, email, enums, state-machine

I want to validate an email address using a state machine.
I know there are other ways to do it like using regular expression, but I want to know can it be done using a state machine.

Any sample example or a good pointer in right direction will be appreciated

Comment: You mean something like... each character readed is an event and will transition to next state until a final state is reached?

Comment: Statemachines are not for validation of values. They are for workflows.

Comment: Yes something like that.Just suppose that we cannot use regex or pattern matcher and we need to validate email pattern.Then how should we go about it.

Comment: @Jens You can implement a regex as a state machine where the input is accepted if you reach a specific terminal node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finite automata (which are special kinds of state machines) accept the same kind of languages (so called *regular languages*) as regular expressions.

So if you have a regular expression that matches all email addresses and nothing else, you can construct a finite automaton that accepts all email addresses and rejects everything else.

See [Wikipeda: Deterministic finite automaton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton) for details.